# How to check whether the first character of a string is a small letter using sas

Tags: sas

I have a variable `NAME`. I want to check whether the first character of this variable is a small letter or not.  `Name` looks like the following:

```
aBMS
BMS
xMS
zVewS
fPP
NBMS
```

I extract the first character of my variable using `first_letter = first(NAME);` Can anyone teach me how to check whether the variable `first_letter` is a small letter or not. Now I did it as follows, but I am wondering if I can achieve this without typing the whole alphabet letters.  `if first_letter = 'a' | first_letter = 'b' |first_letter = 'c' ... then dummy = 1`.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sas, but in other languages you can do something along the lines of `if first_letter >= 'a' && first_letter <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl Regular Expression can also provide an alternative:

```
    data have;
    input NAME $;
cards;  
aBMS
BMS
xMS
zVewS
fPP
NBMS
;   
run;


data want;
set have;
if prxmatch('/^[[:lower:]]/', name)>0;
run;
```

This is very straightforward, literally checking if the first letter is the lower case. ^ to define the beginning of the string, [[:lower:]] is to match the lower case characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `compress` function with `kl` as the 3rd argument tells SAS to keep only lowercase characters, so the following works correctly for all cases, including non-alphanumeric first characters:

```
data have;
    input NAME $;
cards;  
aBMS
BMS
xMS
zVewS
fPP
NBMS
;   
run;

data want;
    set have;
    FLAG  = compress(first(NAME),,'lk') ne '';
run;
```

N.B. The third argument for `compress` is a feature that was only added to SAS in version 9.1, so this won't work in earlier versions of SAS.

Also, this will work both in a where clause and in a data step if statement - by contrast, the `between` syntax used in Gordon's answer is only valid in a where clause. A variant of this approach that would work in both cases is:

```
data want;
    set have;
    /*Yes, SAS supports character inequalities!*/
    FLAG = 'a' <= first(NAME) <= 'z';
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

first(string) eq lowcase(first(string))

This will also true be if the first character in the string is not alphabet character.  You don't mention if that scenario is to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

SAS `proc sql` is case sensitive, so the following should work:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from t
    where substring(t.name from 1 for 1) between 'a' and 'z';
```

Comment: I don't think `proc sql` is special in this regard - to the best of my knowledge *all* string comparisons in SAS are case sensitive.

Comment: What happens when you have a character like ø?  I don't believe that is going to work.

Comment: @data_null_ . . . The characters in the question are all basic ASCII characters (which is not unusual for SAS strings) and the OP mentions "typing the whole alphabet".  If the OP wants extended characters, s/he should mention that.  I don't know if it is you, but a downvote (for this reason) seems rude given the question.